# getting name and value from xmltype attribute in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, plsql

### Description

Hello, I have a problem with extracting attribute names and values from XMLType value in Oracle.
Basically, I have a table, let's say `TableA`, which has a XMLType column, let's call it `TableA_config`. Values in `TableA_config` have structure like this:
`<TableAConfig someAttribute1="value1" someAttribute2="value2" someAttribute3="value3" />`. The number of attributes and their names may vary and are not known beforehand.
What I need to do is (for each row) create new XMLElement called `TableAConfigList`, which contains XMLElements called `TableAConfig` and each of those has two attributes: `name` and `value`. Now, number of `TableAConfig` nodes must be equal to number of attributes in `TableA_config` column, and each holds name of corresponding attribute in `name` attribute and its value in `value` attribute.

### Example

From:

```
<TableAConfig someAttribute1="value1" someAttribute2="value2" someAttribute3="value3" />
```

I should get:

```
<TableAConfigList>
    <TableAConfig name="someAttribute1" value="value1"/>
    <TableAConfig name="someAttribute2" value="value2"/>
    <TableAConfig name="someAttribute3" value="value3"/>
</TableAConfigList>
```

### What I tried

I came up with idea to create a `XMLTable` from `TableA_config` column value and in it create two columns, which I can later select. It looks like this (it is a fragment of a bigger query):

```
SELECT XMLElement("TableAConfigList",
    (SELECT
        XMLAgg(
           XMLElement("TableAConfig",
                XMLAttributes(
                    tmp."attr_name" as "name",
                    tmp."attr_text" as "value"
                )
            )
        ) from XMLTable('/TableAConfig/@*'
            passing TableA.TableA_config
            columns
               "attr_name" varchar(30) path 'name()',
               "attr_text" varchar(30) path 'text()'
        ) tmp
    )
) from dual
```

But now i get:

```
<TableAConfigList>
    <TableAConfig name="someAttribute1"></TableAConfig>
    <TableAConfig name="someAttribute2"></TableAConfig>
    <TableAConfig name="someAttribute3"></TableAConfig>
</TableAConfigList>
```

There is no `value`. However, if I remove `name` from `XMLAttributes` it shows up. From:

```
SELECT XMLElement("TableAConfigList",
    (SELECT
        XMLAgg(
           XMLElement("TableAConfig",
                XMLAttributes(
                    tmp."attr_text" as "value"
                )
            )
        ) from XMLTable('/TableAConfig/@*'
            passing TableA.TableA_config
            columns
               "attr_name" varchar(30) path 'name()',
               "attr_text" varchar(30) path 'text()'
        ) tmp
    )
) from dual
```

I get:

```
<TableAConfigList>
    <TableAConfig value="value1"></TableAConfig>
    <TableAConfig value="value2"></TableAConfig>
    <TableAConfig value="value3"></TableAConfig>
</TableAConfigList>
```

I thought that maybe, for some reason, there can only be one attribute created this way, but if I add a new one by hardcoding it, it shows up in result, like this:

```
SELECT XMLElement("TableAConfigList",
    (SELECT
        XMLAgg(
           XMLElement("TableAConfig",
                XMLAttributes(
                    tmp."attr_text" as "value",
                    'testValue' as "testAttribute"
                )
            )
        ) from XMLTable('/TableAConfig/@*'
            passing TableA.TableA_config
            columns
               "attr_name" varchar(30) path 'name()',
               "attr_text" varchar(30) path 'text()'
        ) tmp
    )
) from dual
```

Result:

```
<TableAConfigList>
    <TableAConfig value="value1" testAttribute="testValue"></TableAConfig>
    <TableAConfig value="value2" testAttribute="testValue"></TableAConfig>
    <TableAConfig value="value3" testAttribute="testValue"></TableAConfig>
</TableAConfigList>
```

Putting in `XMLAttributes` both columns and hardcoded one gives me `name` and `testAttribute`, but no `value`.

Could someone tell me is it because I miss something terribly obvious, is it a bug or am I doing it completely wrong. I am pretty new to Oracle and PL/SQL and could really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with your first attempt. While evaluating the XPath, when you are inside the attribute list with `/TableAConfig/@*`, you don't need `text()` to get the value of the attribute inside it. You are already at the attribute level so using just a "dot" `.` for current node would be sufficient.

So try something like this -

```
SELECT XMLElement("TableAConfigList",
    (SELECT
        XMLAgg(
           XMLElement("TableAConfig",
                XMLAttributes(
                    tmp."attr_name" as "name",
                    tmp."attr_text" as "value"
                )
            )
        ) from XMLTable('/TableAConfig/@*'
            passing TableA.TableA_config
            columns
               "attr_name" varchar(30) path 'name()',
               "attr_text" varchar(30) path '.'
        ) tmp
    )
) from dual
```

The only difference from your first attempt is the xpath of the `value` attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works :). After asking my question here, I did some trial and error (out of desperation) and turns out that xpath `'/'` also works. Is there any difference between `'.'` and `'/'`? Anyway, accepting answer :)

Comment: Yes. '.' points to the current node and '/' points to the root node. However in this case, since we have already traversed down to the attribute level in the `XMLTABLE` clause, the `PATH` clause (xpath) is evaluated after we are already at the attribute level using `/@*`. So the current node is also the root node of the remaining XML piece. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XMLTRANSFORM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions254.htm#SQLRF06171) too:

```
select xmltransform(
       xmltype('<TableAConfig someAttribute1="value1" someAttribute2="value2" someAttribute3="value3" />'),
       xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="TableAConfig">
<TableAConfigList>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:element name="TableAConfig" >
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
</TableAConfigList>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'))
from dual
```